# Method that gets an element's child text, regardless of whether in <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm building a scraper in `Node.js` and have come up against a slight problem. I'm trying to build a function which gets an element's text, regardless of whether it's embedded in a `<p>` tag, in a `<span>` or just a `<div>` with text inside.

The following currently works ONLY for text contained in `<p>` tags:

```
function getDescription(product){
    var text =[];
    $('.description *')
        .each(function(i, elem) {
            var dirty = $(this).text();
            var clean = sanitize(dirty).trim();
            if (clean.length){
                text.push(clean);
            }
        });
    text.join(',');
    sanitize(text).trim();
    return text;
}
```

This works for code like this:

```
<div class="description">
    <p>Test test test</p>
</div>
```

But doesn't work for this:

```
<div class="description">
    Test test test
</div>
```

*For reference, the `sanitize` and `trim` functions are part of [`Node Validator`](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator), but that's not particularly relevant to my problem - they just take a string and remove whitespace from it.*

Any ideas on what I can do to make the one function work for BOTH instances? To add insult to injury, I'm slightly more limited as `node` uses the [`cheerio`](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) library to replicate some functions of `jQuery`, but not all of them.

Comment: what do you want to be returned if you have something like:
<div class="description">
Test1 test1 test1
<p>Test2 test2 test2</p>
</div>
?

Comment: I'm confused, are you basically asking how to do [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text) yourself?

Comment: @JonasGrumann In that case, I'd want "test1 test1 test1 test2 test2 test2" to be returned.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino See above - `text()` is working when the text is inside a `p` tag inside my selector, but when the text is inside the selected element itself it's returning nothing. This is `cheerio` rather than strict `jquery` so `text()` might behave slightly differently here.

Answer (score 6):

Use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead of *

```
function getDescription(product){
    var text =[];
    $('.description').contents()
        .each(function(i, elem) {
            var dirty = $(this).text();
            var clean = sanitize(dirty).trim();
            if (clean.length){
                text.push(clean);
            }
        });
    text.join(',');
    sanitize(text).trim();
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Ah damn, that's what I meant. Corrected my answer. +1.

Comment: +1, if only for `sanitize(dirty)`. For no obvious reason, that amused me (and it works, too, otherwise no-vote, obviously). =)

Comment: @DavidThomas I'd looked at only the contents problem, there are multiple other problems here like `text.join(',');` and `sanitize(text).trim();`

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(".description").contents()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)).

The `*` only selects element nodes, but not text nodes.

Comment: As above, this is using `cheerio` which is an offshoot of `jquery` for Node. `contents()` isn't an option here, but simply keeping `text()` and removing the `+ ' *'` from my selector did the trick, as you were first if you edit your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Jascination Maybe not necessary in this case, but you can always fall back to the plain DOM methods, if needed. Every DOM node has a `childNodes` collection and a you can traverse. Writing a recursive function that collects all text node descendants if a node is a matter of five lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerText`:

```
var text =[];
$('.description').each(function(i, elem) {
    var dirty = elem.innerText;

    var clean = sanitize(dirty).trim();
    if (clean.length){
        text.push(clean);
    }
});
```